# How can I trigger a function when the text of a hidden input box changes by an external jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The user will not be directly changing the input box, so keyup/keypress is not useful. Since onchange is triggered when the input box loses focus, I cannot use `change()` or `onchange()`. The external jquery is modifying the input, so I cannot use `trigger()`. Is there any other method to do this without using `setInterval`?

Comment: call the function inside external jquery after you modify the input content..

Comment: If the external jQuery library does not raise an event after modifying the value, or even have a callback function you can provide, then `setInterval` is the only real (yet very ugly) solution. What is the plugin?

Comment: The other plugin is on another website.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there's a DOM LEVEL EVENT that fires when anything changes, but it's not supported by all browsers, in fact, i think only Chrome and FireFox does.

Here's a link to a solution for this: [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

hope it helps.